# Как распределить данные из сервера по тегам?

Tags: javascript

надо распределить данные(body) по тегам [CODE](https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-field-g91tq?file=/src/index.js:0-490)

```js
//import "./styles.css";

let p = [...document.querySelectorAll(".description__product-text")];

const baseURL = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts";

// логика функции

function sendRequest(url) {
  return fetch(url).then((res) => res.json());
}

// добавляем текст из сервера

sendRequest(baseURL)
  .then((data) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      p[i].innerHtml = data.body[i];
    }
  })
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <main class="shoro">
        <div class="description">
          <div class="description__product">
            <h3 class="description__product-name">Title 1</h3>
            <!--  добавляем текст из сервера-->
            <p class="description__product-text"></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </main>
      <main class="shoro">
        <div class="description">
          <div class="description__product">
            <h3 class="description__product-name">Title 2</h3>
            <!--  добавляем текст из сервера-->
            <p class="description__product-text"></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </main>
      <main class="shoro">
        <div class="description">
          <div class="description__product">
            <h3 class="description__product-name">Title 3</h3>
            <!--  добавляем текст из сервера-->
            <p class="description__product-text"></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </main>
    </div>

    <!-- <script src="src/index.js"></script>-->
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Похоже проблема в строке `.then((json) => console.log(json));`. `console.log()` не возвращает аргумент. Правильно бы было `.then((json) => { console.log(json); return json; } );`

Comment: return + `data.body[i]` => `data[i].body`

Comment: ```
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      return (p[i].innerHtml = data[i].body);
    }
```
нету результата